# Java - Extract data from Document with Regex

Tags: java, regex

I have a dataset of resume and I want to extract data from each resume 
I will give an example as a sample to what I need

```
String test= "Worked in Innovision Information System Private Limited as Project Trainee-Content Writing from Date to Date.";
```

I want to extract the `company name`, `role (designation)`, and `Date (From-to)`

I'm new to regex so please correct me if I'm wrong

the first thing I tried to extract each one of them separately

```
String regexStr5="Worked in:? \\w+" ;
String regexStr6 ="as:? ([a-zA-Z ]+)";
```

and for the date `Date : (Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec) \d{1,2}, \d{4}`

How can I put them all together in the same regex?!! 
and print the `company-Name +role+date`

Comment: Is the test string structured like that in all resumes ?

Comment: No absolutely not but this is a sample that I took from one resume

Comment: I'm handling an unstructured resume and each applicant write in his/her way and I want to cover all the possibilities and this is one of them

Comment: Then it's tough to match pattern. Regex is context free which means it doesn't understand like we do. You have to feed pattern syntax to match those. You can match string like [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/zO1yL4/1). For which it has to be structured.

Comment: yes I know so that in my work I will define many rules to cover all the situation but I put one to know how then I will cover the rest i.e.(consider the test string structured like that in all resumes)

Comment: Well then does my demo regex works for your purpose ?

Comment: yes it's perfect thanx very much,, mm sorry for pothering you but could you write your answer to accept it :)))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A literal string match would be just fine for above test string.

**Regex:** `Worked in (.*) as (.*) from (.*) to (.*).`

**Replacement to do:** `Company Name: \1\nRole (designation): \2\nDate: \3 to \4`

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zO1yL4/1)**